# Check if a row is in a list and compare it to other rows in that table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am using ADO.NET query to select the employee id's of all the employees whose have a location x, y or z and are working under a supervisor.

This is the query that I am working with:

```
SELECT  e.Employee_OID
FROM    Employee e
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT  1
                FROM    Employee e1 
                WHERE   e.Employee_OID = e1.Supervisor_OID
                AND     e1.Active_f = 'A')
AND     e.Location_OID IN (123, 22)
AND     e.Active_f = 'A'
```

I want to convert this is into a LINQ expression, I am a beginner to LINQ and EF, can someone guide me into writing this into LINQ?

This is what I have so far:

```
var supervisors = (from employee in Employee
         where employee.location_OID == "???"  //I have ID's in a list here
         select employee.Employee_OID).Any();
```

Comment: @All downvoters, thankyou! But providing a helpful link like [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b), would have been appreciated.

Comment: @faizanjehangir we are not here do the search for you. Before asking a question make your homework a research a little bit.

Comment: The issues in this post are generally relevant and recognizable if you have done any work with EF.  This question has right and wrong answers and is unlikely to solicit debate.  The close votes are not rational.  I think this is an OK question and have [posted so on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180021/quick-downvotes-for-question-that-looks-simple-but-is-not)

Comment: @Andomar thank you for a generous response. But I suppose the community can be hostile sometimes around. Anyhow, the opinions have to be respected. It discourages one's opportunity to learn and explore something new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using EF 4.0 or higher, you can use `Contains()` to check if an item is in a list:

```
where yourList.Contains(employee.location_OID)
```

The `exists` subquery could be done with `Any()`:

```
where employee.Any(e1 => e.Employee_OID == e1.Supervisor_OID &&
                         e1.Active_f == "A")
```